# SQL count longest True sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have a problem, I want to make a ranked list of the user with the highest number of correct quiz answers.

I save the answers into a table and if the answer is true, I safe true and if not I safe false.

So now I have to count the longest true sequence, right? I found the function `ROW_NUMBER()` but I don't understand it. So the table name `resultat` with
columns `(user_id, Date, solved(boolean))`

I now need the SQL for this. Thanks for taking time for me :)

Comment: Add sample data and expected output to the question

Comment: so f.e 
user_id    solved
1                 true
1                 true
1                 false
2                 true
2                 true
2                 true
2                 true
2                 false
1                 true
1                 false


output:
user 2 (with 4 right answers in a row)
user 1 (with 3 right answers in a row

Comment: Do you want to find the users with the most total right answers or the users with the most consecutive right answers ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS solved_total FROM resultat WHERE solved = true GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY solved_total DESC;
```

Notice that this is plain SQL and not Postgre related.

Comment: the problem i have is, i dont want to count all trues. i want to have the longest row of trues. 
f.e if i have 6 straigts right answers and then i make a mistake, my counter is 6
so if i have 8 answers right in a row, it will be 8 not 14